# Function to select a range of data files with different number extensions

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

I have a folder that contains file names with different number extensions. For example:

```
run1_101.txt
run2_103.txt
exp4_104.txt
sulphur1_105.txt
```

This folder gets updated with new files each time a different experiment is performed.

I need to extract 1 column(peak area) from each txt file. The problem is, I have about 100 files I need to do this for and some files may have different names(name_101 etc).

I want to write a function that will select the file in the folder within a range that I give it. E.g. :

```
def select_file(a,b, file_name):
    file_range = np.arange(a,b)
    if file_range in file_name:
        return file_name
```

I then want to write some other functions to select the column i want for each file and write it to a DataFrame using pandas.

Comment: Maybe glob can help you? https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: Yes this will e useful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the glob library to match file name patterns: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

i.e:

```
    list = []    
    for filelist in [glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in ['*%i*' % x for x in range(a,b+1)] if glob.glob(pattern)]: 
        list += filelist
```

This way you search for all the patterns between the range you specified, searching in the current directory.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, preferably with runnable code, at the moment this is no better than a link-only answer